# Add more attributes to video when I create from script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

From my JavaScript I create a new `video` tag and I add it to my page.

```
var video = $('<video/>', {
                src: '/DownloadAttachment/87674e75-e0e9-4048-b623-6c25e4dd30fc',
                type: 'video/quicktime',
                controls: true,
                width: '100%'
            });
link.html(video);
```

as result I have

```
<video style="width: 100%;" 
       src="/DownloadAttachment/87674e75-e0e9-4048-b623-6c25e4dd30fc" 
       controls="controls" 
       type="video/quicktime">
</video>
```

This is working on Windows and Android but the problem is on iOS, the video doesn't play. I googled a but and the solution is to add some extra attributes like:

```
<video controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' 
       src='/DownloadAttachment/87674e75-e0e9-4048-b623-6c25e4dd30fc' type='video/mp4' 
       muted playsinline />
```

If I add in the code `controls: true` the render returns `controls="controls"`. I can't find a way to add `playsinline`.

### Update

I added `muted` and `playsinline` but the result is the same. I have a blank placeholder.

[image: Blank placeholder]

I updated the html like:

```
<video style="width: 100%;" preload="auto" 
       controls="controls" playsinlin 
       webkit-playsinline>
    <source src="/Comments/DownloadAttachment/2d236789-1626-4983-b614-c5bfc676d063"
            type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But in this case I see a white placeholder with the play button but the video is empty and I can't play it.

How can I fix it? Is there any player that can improve the `video` tag for macOS/iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method by adding the following

```
$(video).attr('playsinline', '');
```

For what you are trying to achieve you may however have more luck using

```
$(video).attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
```

Comment: Oh you are right! I haven’t think about it! I’ll try now. Thank you

Comment: No problem at all let me know how it goes ^^

Comment: JS option not jquery?